# Why is the Globe plugin missing in QGIS 2.17.0 master?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, globe

It seems that the 'Globe' plugin is missing in QGIS 2.17.0 master. Is this a bug or is there something I'm doing wrong:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a Ubuntu issue. Globe is included in OSGeo4W but on Ubuntu qgis-plugin-globe is stuck to 2.14 even though the rest of QGIS 2.16 installed just fine:

[image]

Update:

I got the following explanation on the QGIS mailing list by Jürgen:

> Globe is only include where osgearth 2.7 is available (ie. debian
>   unstable has it, ubuntugis xenial has it IIRC).
>
> For 2.14 it's inverse, there globe is only available where osgearth<2.7 is available.

Comment: Try the ubuntugis version of QGIS. It did install `2.16.0+24xenial-ubuntugis` for me.

Comment: Try a virtual box with Xenial, it saves you a lot of headache if you miss features from trusty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need update your version,to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Meanwhile, I suppose it's an OS related issue. It seems that I've to install the globe plugin separately on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two flavours of QGIS for Ubuntu: `Debian` and `Ubuntugis`.

It seems that only the second has the globe plugin (see http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly-release/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages), while Debian does not (see http://qgis.org/debian-nightly-release/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages).

I have only checked Xenial releases for QGIS 2.16 and nightly, maybe trusty or older have a different packaging.