# Is it possible to extrude a vector layer with QGIS 2.16 Globe plugin?

Tags: qgis, 3d, globe

With the new version of Qgis ( 2.16) it is stated that the extension was rewritten globe .

Is it possible to extrude a vector layer with a height parameter and if it is possible to have the procedure?

[image]

Comment: Informations that I found on the website of Qgis about extension Globe Feature: Globe: Extrude objects

Allow extruding objects into the 3rd dimension.

Either by a fixed value or by an attribute or expression.

This feature was developed by Matthias Kuhn

Comment: I have tried the 64bits version .... not the 32bits ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to get the extrusion to work as well, and the closest thing I've found so far is this: Right click on the layer in qgis, go to Properties, and there should be a 'Globe' section you can play around with.

[image]

You might need to set the height as 10*z or 10*height or something like that. Again, I've tried applying this to my own dataset but it hasn't worked much. Would love to know if you can get it to work.

Comment: Hello
Thank you for the tip of the globe properties in the geographic layer , I had not thought of !
After testing with a fixed value , extrusion works!
By an expression : 1 * ' the name of the column height of the layer ' , extrusion also works with different heights !!
(Do not put the symbol = front ) .

Comment: I didn't find globe option in layer properties (using qgis 3.8.0) I am looking for something related to height/extrusion but through programming and there are different height for different polygons. Please can you help here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337530/polygon-layer-extrusion-pyqgis

Comment: The globe option requires the globe plugin, but that doesn't seem to be come with my qgis 3.8 installation either, and I'm not sure if it's available in qgis versions >3. Perhaps try the steps at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202260/why-is-the-globe-plugin-missing-in-qgis-2-17-0-master?