# Polygon Layer extrusion PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, extrude

I have a **polygon layer (consist of buildings)** and it has different attributes including the **height** attribute. I want to use that **height in order to extrude my all polygons** or give height to my building then export the dxf file. Want to give that height to  my all polygons using the PyQGIS. I am able to find [extrude documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.extrude) but unable to locate any working example as I am confused with two parameters of extrude which is x and y. I guess it should be consist of one parameter of **height only**.

```
extrude(self, x: float, y: float) → QgsGeometry
Returns an extruded version of this geometry.
```

Some code which I have applied without any success(no visual appearance change of polygone)

```
#getting the desired layer
if QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerUpdateName):
    layerUpdate = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerUpdateName)[0]; 

for lu in layerUpdate.getFeatures():
    print (lu["Height"])
    #lu.geometry().extrude(lu["Height"],lu["Height"])
    #testExtrude(lu,lu.geometry())
    #geom = lu.geometry().asPolygone()
    lu.setGeometry(lu.geometry().extrude(lu["Height"],lu["Height"]))
```

Comment: You could find a [test example from the QGIS GitHub repository](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsgeometry.py#L1818)

Comment: As far as i can see, extrude here doesn't mean adding a hight to a geometry, so it does not constructs a 3D volume object (like in ESRI's ArcScene).

Comment: @AndreasMüller do you mean we can give height to polygon in qgis?

Comment: @Joseph thanks for the example trying to learn it. but what does x,y means ? it should be consist of single overload with height parameter only?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254710/how-to-create-a-3d-shapefile-with-qgis-from-values-stored-in-the-attribute-table/254712 is a different approach

Comment: What is the purpose of the extrusion? Is it just for visualisation, or is it important to create a new geometry?

Comment: I want to extrude them then import to modeling tool for better visual appearance.

Answer (score 3):

### What about forgoing 0.5D?

`;-)`

If you don't really need extruded polygons, bot only a 3D-like representation, the **2.5D rendering option** might work for you.

You can apply a calculated value to be used as "extrusion" height, based on one or multiple fields.

[image]

Of course this is not a *real* extrusion, but might suffice in many cases.

Comment: I am looking for actual extrusion as i have to export it for 3d modelling tool and make proper building with actual height.

Comment: exported the layer in dxf file format and there is no height.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment where you say:

> I am looking for actual extrusion as i have to export it for 3d modelling tool and make proper building with actual height.

I would recommend installing the qgis2threejs plugin, setting up your extrusion there, and exporting as glTF:

[image]

[image: glTF export]

glTF is a JSON 3D format that can be imported into a 3D modelling software. For example, I have successfully exported extruded building polygons projected onto a DEM draped with ortophoto to Blender 3D using this method.

Wikipedia for glTF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF

Although a caveat is that you most likely will lose georeferencing with this process.

Comment: Gitf file is not opening in Max

Comment: I am trying to use this extustion but it giving me error https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254710/how-to-create-a-3d-shapefile-with-qgis-from-values-stored-in-the-attribute-table

Comment: Hi hexamon! thannks for the answer, i tried it again. And the scale of the model is very narrow? How do i scale?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan Could you elaborate a bit? What do you mean by "narrow"? And is it narrow after you've imported it to Max? Assuming that you mean that the scale is wrong in one axis, I would think the problem is either the projection you are using when exporting from QGIS or some import issue in Max.

Comment: I exported gltf file and imported in blender(as only blender support it not max). Then simply i make the fbx from blender.

Comment: Maybe there is any extra setting require in scene settings. There is Display of cooridinate and based width. what is this?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. Could you describe what you mean by "narrow"? If you are using Blender you can also use https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS to import and extrude the data directly without using QGIS.