# Qgis globe plugin (2.16) missing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, globe, ubuntugis

I just upgraded from Qgis 2.14 to 2.16 and I can't get the Globe plugin to work. Apparently, under Ubuntu it is necessary to install it separately. But in the Ubuntugis repository, only version 2.14 of qgis-plugin-globe is available and Synaptic refuses to install it:

```
qgis-plugin-globe:
  Depends: qgis (=2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1) but 1:2.16.0+20trusty is to be installed
 Depends: libopenscenegraph100v5 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libosgearth3 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libosgearthqt3 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libosgearthutil3 but it is not going to be installed
```

Any idea how to get this plugin to work?

Comment: probably related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202260/globe-plugin-missing-qgis-2-17-0-master

Comment: Indeed! But I still posted since there was no solution found on the other thread (and since it's a different Qgis version)

Comment: Thanks all for the replies! I put underdark's one as the solution but you actually all brought useful info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need Ubuntu Xenial to get Globe for 2.16.

I got the following explanation on the QGIS mailing list by Jürgen:

> Globe is only include where osgearth 2.7 is available (ie. debian unstable has it, ubuntugis xenial has it IIRC).
>
> For 2.14 it's inverse, there globe is only available where osgearth<2.7 is available.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 I have QGIS 2.14 and osgearth 2.4.0+dfsg-6 and yet Globe plugin do not show in plugins list

Answer (score 3):

Simple rule: If you want to stick to a Ubuntu LTS (14.04), you must stick to QGIS LTR (2.14.4). Or get the latest from both worlds (16.04 and 2.16.0).

The developers decided to do no additional backporting. You might well pay a developer for it if you can't/won't compile yourself.

Comment: That's a new rule to me. Can you point to a source?

Comment: I'm afraid I can not ;-) But it makes some sense to me.

Comment: It does indeed. But if this is a written rule, I will be very happy to know so I can adjust :)
As far as I know, this is just a coincidence. Normally things are pretty much compatible across different versions.

Answer (score 2):

As outlined by @underdark, the globe plugin which is shipped with QGIS 2.16 depends on osgEarth 2.7 which is not available out of the box on ubuntu 14.04.

Your options are:

- Upgrade to [yakkety yak](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/osgearth) or use [xenial with ubuntugis unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable)
- Stick to QGIS 2.14
- Compile osgEarth and then QGIS (with globe enabled) yourself

  - Directly from source (when compiling QGIS you will have to set some paths to osgEarth includ/lib directories)
  - You can try to backport packages from yakkety

Comment: I had QGIS 2.16 installed on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and was wondering why the globe plugin worked for me, but not for others...