# QGIS 2.14.x missing Globe-PlugIn on Fedora 23/24

Tags: qgis, 3d, globe, fedora

QGIS 2.14.3 on Fedora 23 does not provide the Globe-Plugin. The package qgis-plugin-globe like used in *buntu is also not available. Also postinstalling osgearth did not help. Anyone a solution to this ?

Comment: Please have a look at the compatibility notes listed in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203181/qgis-globe-plugin-2-16-missing-on-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#fedora lists two alternatives for QGIS on Fedora.

If both do not have the plugin, you will have to compile QGIS from source with the plugin yourself. You might fail, because the Fedora maintainers might not exclude the plugin without a reason.

As an alternative, you could install a virtual box with a current debian or ubuntu OS inside. Or [file a ticket](https://github.com/fedora-infra/fedora-packages/issues/new) to get it included.